# If for all $b$ with integer entries, the system $Ax=b$ has a solution $x$ with integer entries, then $\det A=\pm 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> A vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be integral if each component of $x$ is an integer. Let $A$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix with integer entries. Prove that the system of equations $Ax=b$ has an integral solution for every integral vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $\det A=\pm 1$.

The sufficiency follows at once from Cramer's rule.

If some column of $A$, say $a_j$, contains only even integers, then, by Cramer's rule agian, the solution to $Ax=\frac{1}{2}a_j$ is non-integral. How to deal with the other cases?

Comment: See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135482/inverse-of-integer-matrix-with-determinant-pm-1

Comment: You have solutions $x_{k} = A^{-1} b_{k}$ where $b_{k}$ is the $k$'th basis vector, aka $(0,0,...1,0,\dots 0)$ . Basically the columns of $A^{-1}$ are solutions. If they are all integral, so is the determinant of $A^{-1}$. So both $\det(A)$ and $\frac{1}{\det(A)}$ must be integers.